# fields values are empty in Javascript validations

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a form, I use the javascript validations on it. After showing the alert when it redirect on form, it empty all fields values .
 In custom form:

```
form method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal"  name="jform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group formSep">
<label for="u_fname" class="control-label">oDesk Id</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text"  class="input-xlarge" name="odesk" value="" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group formSep">
<label for="u_fname" class="control-label">Hours</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text"  class="input-xlarge" name="hours" value="" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="asubmit">Submit</button>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-gebo" />
</div>
```

In views.py:-

```
@csrf_exempt
def odesk(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        odeskid=request.POST['odesk']
        hours = request.POST['hours']
        feedback= request.POST['feedback']
        if odeskid == '':
            return HttpResponse('<script> alert("fill odesk id here ");  document.location.href="/odesks/"; </script>')
        if hours == '':
            return HttpResponse('<script> alert("fill total hours");  document.location.href="/odesks/"; </script>')
        if feedback == '':
            return HttpResponse('<script> alert("fill feedback ");  document.location.href="/odesks/"; </script>')
        else:
            getintable = odesktable(odeskid = request.POST['odesk'], hours = request.POST['hours'], feedback = request.POST['feedback'])
        getintable.save()
        return render_to_response('odeskform.html')
    else:
        return render_to_response('odeskform.html')
```

Its working but after alert when it redirect it clear the all fields.

Comment: Well, yes. Because you're redirecting back to the empty form page. Why are you doing that? Why, if you want Javascript validation, are you not doing that validation on the front-end in Javascript rather than in Python? Why are you not using Django forms? Why, in fact, are you using Django at all if you're avoiding both forms and CSRF protection?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Point in case.